# Excel Macro to find last modified date of file

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me out with an Excel VBA macro to search for files in various directories provide in column B, based on keywords given in column A and return "File Present"/"File Not Present" in column C and return last modified date and time  of file in column D.

Example

```
Keyword | FolderPath        | Result / last modified date & time 
--------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------
1234    | E:\Documents\ABC  |
```

I'm new to Excel Macros. Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
FileDateTime(Path as String)
```

More detail visit
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php

Answer (score 0):

For Using macro follow this steps:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> => Opening VBA IDE
2. From menu bar `Insert > Module`  => Adding a module to your Excel
3. Write your macro code.

You can use this macro:

```
Sub UpdateFileDate()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim fileTemp As Object
  Dim strDate As Date

  ' Open library of Microsoft Scripting Runtime
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
     strTemp = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & " ")
     If (strTemp = "") Then Exit For

     If (fso.FolderExists(strTemp)) Then

        ' Set a min value to strDate
        strDate = DateTime.DateSerial(-1000, 1, 1)

        ' Check All files in the folder
        For Each fileTemp In fso.GetFolder(strTemp).Files
           If (strDate < fileTemp.DateLastModified) Then
               strDate = fileTemp.DateLastModified
           End If
        Next

        If (strDate <> DateTime.DateSerial(-1000, 1, 1)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = CStr(strDate)
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "No File"
        End If
     End If
  Next i

End Sub
```